# Power BI : line grouping

Tags: powerbi, line, group

I begin to use Power BI, and I don't know how to group lines.
I have this kind of data :

```
api   user  01/07/21  02/07/21  03/07/21 ...
a     25    null      3          4
b     25    1         null       2
c     25    1         4          5
a     30    4         3          5
b     30    3         2          2
c     30    1         1          3
```

And I would like to have the sum of the values per user, not by api and user

```
user  01/07/21  02/07/21  03/07/21 ...
25    2         7          11
30    8         6          10
```

Do you know how to do it please ?

Comment: Just remove `api` column.

Comment: I had already tried it but it didn't help

Comment: I have null values, it can be the problem ?

Comment: We can't guess. There are no nulls in your sample data. To be able to get a helpful answers, you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I update it

Answer (score 1):

I created a table with your sample data (make sure your values are treated as numbers):

[image: Table]

Then create a Matrix visual, with "user" in Rows and your desired columns in the Values section:

[image: Matrix]